# I want to fetch data from twig for more than one object from the database in PDO

Tags: php, pdo, twig

This is my code for the method to fetch data from the database. I am passing those data as objects to use in html file.

```
     * Get news details
     * 
     * @return object
     */
    public static function getNews()
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM news 
                ORDER BY date DESC';

        $db = static::getDB();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, get_called_class());

        $stmt->execute();

        $news = $stmt->fetch();

        return $news;
    }
```

Now, this is my rendering function for the index page.. `getNews()` is method of `News` class:

```
     * Show the index page
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $news = new News();
        $news = $news::getNews();

        View::renderTemplate('Home/index.html', [
            'news' => $news
        ]); 
    }
```

After news object is got.. I wanted to add posts according to descending timestamp. The problem I got is that `$news` is not taking data of whole table. It only shows data of latest object.

```
    <div class="row">

                {% for eachnews in news %}

                    <div class="col-4 mt-4">
                        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                            <img src="/uploads/news/{{ eachnews.fullfilename }}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">{{ eachnews.title }}</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">{{ eachnews.description }}</p>
                                <a href="news" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                {% endfor %}

            </div>
```

Every suggestion and answer are highly appreciated. Please ask me, if my problems are not clear.

Comment: can you share what `$news` looks like, e.g. `var_dump($news)`

Comment: I think I don't have to show you var_dump because it was simply showing only one row.... But again thanks for asking... And @Arcesilas has made it clear in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `PDO::fetch()`, which only returns one record. You need to use `PDO::fetchAll()` to fetch... all records.

```
    public static function getNews()
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM news 
                ORDER BY date DESC';

        $db = static::getDB();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, get_called_class());

        $stmt->execute();

        $news = $stmt->fetchAll();

        return $news;
    }
```

See [`PDO::fetch()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) and [`PDO::fetchAll()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) documentation pages.

BTW, in this very specific case, you don't need to prepare the statement, since:

- you don't use it more than once
- you don't inject user data

Therefore, you may simply use [`PDO::query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php):

```
    public static function getNews()
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM news 
                ORDER BY date DESC';

        $db = static::getDB();

        return $db->query($sql, PDO::FETCH_CLASS, get_called_class());
    }
```

Never use this method if you need to inject user input (input that user may modify, like URL argument, form input, etc.). Also, prepared statements have better performances when you need to execute the query multiple times (with different parameters, for example).